# Cannot bind to the property or column on the DataSource

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a winform C# SQL 2008 App...

i have one Daily Call Report form that crashes on execution, meaning it throws "Cannot bind to the property or column Sr_No on the DataSource" exception and points to program.cs form ->

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Daily_Call_Report());
    }
```

i have one dataset on the form load events of Daily Call Report. Heres how it looks..

```
try
        {
        SqlConnection last1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=2011-GOA-RCC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IOB_Comm;Integrated Security=True");
        last1.Open();
        SqlCommand lasts = new SqlCommand();
        lasts.Connection = last1;
        lasts.CommandText = "Select Top 1 Sr_No from DCR Order By Sr_No Desc ";
        lasts.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader darw = lasts.ExecuteReader();
        darw.Read();
        label21.Text = darw[@"Sr_No"].ToString();

            int last = Convert.ToInt32(label21.Text);
            int next = last + 1;
            label21.Text = next.ToString();

        darw.Close();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        //to populate gridview
        SqlCommand datvi = new SqlCommand();
        datvi.Connection = last1;
        datvi.CommandText = "Select * from DCR";
        datvi.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter swe = new SqlDataAdapter(datvi);
        DataSet dv1 = new DataSet();

        swe.Fill(dv1);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dv1.Tables[0];

        last1.Close();

            //code which allows custom date and time to choose...
        {

            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd - MM - yyyy HH:mm";

            dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "dd - MM - yyyy HH:mm";

        }
        }
```

There are absolutely no databindings on any of form controls what so ever...

and and all help will be appreciated... 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I believe is that you are using ExecuteNonQuery when you expect data back. Why not do this instead.

```
var dataSets = new DataSet();
        using (var connx = new SqlConnection(LastUsedConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from DCR", connx);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(dataSets);
            }
            finally
            {
                connx.Close();
            }
        }
```